# Keeping footer at the bottom with Bootstrap on Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, footer

I'm trying to keep the footer I've done with Bootstrap on the bottom of the page. I've tried some solutions written on the net, yet no one worked or if it did, it'd mess all my footer (or entire page) up. That's my footer.php file rn:

```html
<footer>
 <div class="container-fluid" style="padding-bottom:22px;">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-4" align="center">
    <h4> RANDOM </h4>
    <p>
     <strong>Lorem</strong>: <br>
     Lorem Ipsum 00 <br>
     0000 Text <br>
     <strong>Tel</strong>: <a href="tel: +101234567"> +1.01234567 </a>
    </p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-4" align="center">
    <h4> RANDOM </h4>
    <p>
     <strong>Text</strong>: <br>
     12:00 - 16:00 / 18:30 - 00:00 <br>
     <strong>Text</strong> <br>
     12:00 - 16:00 / 18:30 - 00:00
    </p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-4" align="center">
    <h4> SOCIAL NETWORK </h4>
    <a href="#" target="_blank"> <i class="fab fa-facebook fa-2x" style="color: #333333;"></i> </a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="container-fluid bg-light" align="center" style="padding-top:22px; padding-bottom:22px;">
  <p style="font-family: lato; font-size: 14px; color: #515050; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
   ©Random • Sample, Text • Tel: +1 01234567 • <a href="#" target="_blank">Privacy Policy</a>
  </p>
 </div>
</footer>

<?php wp_footer(); ?>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually positioning the footer fixed would do the trick:

```
.your-footer-class {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Which solutions have you tried?

Here's a good explanation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Layout_cookbook/Sticky_footers

And here are 5 ways to do it: https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/

Comment: Tried with that, it kinda works. I mean, the footer is always at the bottom, but it's always on top of everything. I'm not aiming for a sticky footer, but just to make it always at the bottom of the page even if there's not enough content.

I've mostly tried some css attributes, I honestly do not remember all of them, but some had the "display: flex" in it.

Comment: Footer always at the bottom is pretty much a sticky footer, no?

For the "even if there's not enough content" case you can use body { min-height: 100vh; }

Comment: Well, yes, the footer at the bottom could be considered a sticky one, yet making it totally sticky, it'd go over the content of the page, so it's kinda bad considering my footer is kinda big. 

To make you understand what I'm looking for, that's the page I'm working on right now, just to test out things: http://darkthemeftw.altervista.org/negozio/


The footer starts where the time starts, so having it always on top would bother people out, if it'd be a real website. 

I've tried with the body min-height, but it didn't work out, either with a 100% or 100vh.

Comment: Either it's sticky or not - if it's sticky then of course it goes over the rest of the page. If you give the footer a background color it won't show both of the contents on top of each other.

Comment: Oh, or did you mean that the footer should stick to the bottom of the page if the page doesn't have enough content and otherwise should be at the end of the content?

Comment: https://codepen.io/piko_/pen/LYYYYQx?editors=1111
(minus the scrollbars, couldn't fix that in the short time I had)

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you had inserted the `get_footer()` in index.php file instead of `wp_footer()` in footer.php & its a worst way to declare scripts tag in footer load your scripts in function.php file with this methods:

```
function wpdocs_theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_theme_name_scripts' );
```